# How to add selectAll/deselectAll buttons on top of clrCheckbox?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

First of all I am neither a front end dev. nor have experience in javascript/html/angular etc. This question might be easy to solve but I couldn't find a proper/working solution because I don't know the problem. I am trying to add already working "Select All" and "Deselect All" buttons on top of checkboxes. But for some reason they either doesn't show up or they are displayed at the bottom, right next to already existing, same buttons. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="widget form-group">

    <clr-checkbox-container>
        <label>
            {{schema.title}}
        </label>
        <clr-control-helper>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="selectAll()" >Select All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="deSelectAll()" >Deselect All</button>
        </clr-control-helper>
        <clr-checkbox-wrapper *ngFor="let option of schema.items.oneOf"  class="checkbox">

            <input clrCheckbox [attr.name]="name"
                   value="{{option.enum[0]}}" type="checkbox"
                   [attr.disabled]="schema.readOnly"
                   (change)="onCheck($event.target)"
                   [checked]="checked[option.enum[0]] ? true : null"/>
            <label>{{option.description}}</label>
        </clr-checkbox-wrapper>
        <clr-control-helper>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="selectAll()" >Select All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="deSelectAll()" >Deselect All</button>
        </clr-control-helper>

    </clr-checkbox-container>
</div>
```

I have tried to copy/paste this part to different places like monkey and ofc. it didn't work out well.

```
        <clr-control-helper>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="selectAll()" >Select All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="deSelectAll()" >Deselect All</button>
        </clr-control-helper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a look on the [docs for these checkbox containers](https://v2.clarity.design/checkboxes), it seems your usage of the `clr-control-helper` directive is incorrect. This directive seems to be a placeholder for some text below the checkboxes, and there probably is some "css/js magic" going on on it.

I would recommend you insert a new div above the `clr-checkbox-container`, something like this:

```
<div class="widget form-group">
    <div class="your-css-for-positioning">
     <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="selectAll()" >Select All</button>
     <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="deSelectAll()" >Deselect All</button>
    </div>
    <clr-checkbox-container>
        <label>
    ...
```

Comment: I am also suspecting something similar. There are .ts files. Do you think they also could be culprit behind this issue? There is this line in the .ts file `templateUrl: './clr-array-widget.component.html'` The html is the code I provided in the question. I just removed the bottom <clr-control-helper> and nothing has changed. It is still displayed at the bottom of the checkboxes. I will try what you said...

Comment: I am inclined to believe that what causes the position on the bottom is some css. Vote for my answer if it helps you! =-)

Comment: I am still trying. As I said: I have no experience in javascript/html/css/angular/etc... It takes some time :)

Comment: You are absolutely right! I was using it wrong. It doesn't matter where you put the clr-control-helper. It always behaves the same. Now I need a css for positioning.